# Make content visable once Javascript variable reaches particular number

Tags: javascript

I am a bit of a javascript noob. I want to make different content appear on my page changing once a user has clicked 3 links on the page.
So I assume I want a variable which increases on every click of the link and an if statement that makes the content appear only once the variable reaches my desired number. This is what I've got so far:

```
<script>
var pass = 0;
function clicked() {
pass = pass + 1;
}
</script>
```

Then on the links:

```
<a href="example.com" onclick="clicked();">LINK</a>
```

Then on the content

```
<script>    
if (pass > 1) {
document.write('<a href="first.html">First</a><br>') }
else {document.write('<a href="second.htm">Second</a><br>') }
</script>
```

It isn't working and the variable always equals 0. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You 'content script' is only called once (when `pass` is still zero).

You need to check it every time when the link is clicked:

```
var pass = 0;
function clicked() {
   pass = pass + 1;
   if (pass > 1) {
      document.write('<a href="first.html">First</a><br>');
   } else {
      document.write('<a href="second.htm">Second</a><br>');
   }
}
```

Comment: but what if the thing being clicked is a completely different element to the one im changing upon the click?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
var count = 1,
    topics = ['Hello', 'Well...', 'Goodbye'];
function clickHandler() {
  if (count >= 3) {
    changeText(Math.round((Math.random() * 2)));
    count = 1;
  } else {
    count += 1;
  }
}

function changeText(idx) {
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = topics[idx]; 
}
```

When the link is pressed 3 times you'll get random content from the list (`topics`).

What is changed

1. In the `clickHandler` the counter is being reset so each 3 clicks random content will be shown
2. I use `innerHTML` instead of `document.write` - its better practice
3. `count` is checked on each click instead of once like you check `pass`.

Example **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/FgyqW/2/)**.